# When I change the DNS of a dial-up connection, by the time I reconnect it is reset

Tags: networking, dns, dial-up

I have a dial-up connection with a provider whose DNS server is offline erratically. When I change my DNS using the usual method with the Network and Sharing Center to Google DNS, it asks me to reconnect to apply the changes, but when I do so, everything is cleared. I have also used an app called DNS Jumper but that didn't work either.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what happens if you try to change it while you are disconnected?

Comment: I seriously doubt that their DNS servers would be down enough to justify this.  Try disconnecting, changing the DNS settings, restart the computer, check if the settings were kept and retry the connection.  If it still switches back, try the same after disabling your security software.

Comment: @JuliePelletier They actually most of the time are. I only use them because of their extremely cheap unlimited internet plan. 2 out of 3 times I connect I get a online.xxxxx.xx is offline. It still stays the same after all that you have suggested. Basically, the only thing I haven't done is format as I don't have enough time to reinstall everything at the moment.

Comment: @FleetCommand I still get the same result.

Comment: So, if you change the settings and restart, do they remain changed?

Comment: @JuliePelletier No, they just reset back to Manual.

Comment: Did you try disabling all security software, and what Windows version are you using?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I forgot to add that. I'm running Win 10 x64 on the November (1511) update, and I haven't tried disabling Kaspersky.

Comment: Obviously you should try disabling Kaspersky and Windows Defender.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'll do it now and get back to you in a minute.

Comment: @JuliePelletier It doesn't work. Thanks anyway.